# Include a string array column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, c, arrays

I am doing a design project where I need to create a SQL database to interface with my C code. Some of the columns of the tables I need are of the string array type. How do I easily add these columns to my tables. I have pasted below what we have so far. The code has a problem with how I am doing these DECLARE functions.

```
CREATE TABLE parameters
(
Alpha float,
D int,
Stoppers varchar(15),
Param_ID int
);

DECLARE parameters TABLE(Function_Words VARCHAR(211));
INSERT INTO parameters
SELECT Function_Words FROM parametters;

CREATE TABLE author_profiles
( 
Author varchar(255),
Param_ID int
);

DECLARE author_profiles TABLE(WANs VARCHAR(211));
INSERT INTO author_profiles
SELECT WANs FROM author_profiles;
```

EDIT: So it should look like this?

```
CREATE TABLE texts
(
Filename varchar(50), -- post-parsed file
Author varchar(50), 
Author_ID int,
Title varchar(50),
Text_ID int
);

CREATE TABLE WANs
(
Filename varchar(50), -- file name where we write each WAN to
Text_ID int, 
Param_ID int,
WAN_ID int
);

CREATE TABLE parameters
(
Function_Words varchar(211),
Alpha float,    
D int,
Stoppers varchar(15),
Param_ID int
);

CREATE TABLE author_profiles
( 
WANs varchar(211),
Author varchar(255),
Param_ID int
);
```

Comment: When thinking about storing arrays, consider normalizing the way you store the data and then building the string array from multiple rows in a data set.

Comment: Sounds like you're new to creating database tables. Do what sgeddes recommends. Most tables should be designed to "third normal form". Read up on first, second, and third normal form. If you apply those three sets of rules to your tables, you'll do a good job nearly every time. There are times where a good database modeler for good reasons will deviate from third normal form, but it is a rare event, and those are advanced concepts to learn later.